# Can't open file:///// in firefox

Tags: php, html

I have an data that show details of some information. In that table there is `<a>` link that the source from my local IP `\\192.168.182.23`

In `<a>` link I put the source URL like this :

```
<a target="_blank" href="file://///192.168.182.23/dt/rm/<?php echo $status;?>\<?php echo $rm.".txt";?>"><?php echo $rm.".txt";?><?php echo $rm.".txt";?></a>
```

and the output view or result like this :

```
m05171400822.txt <-- a link with source url below:
file://///192.168.182.23/dt/rm/pass/m05171400822.txt
```

For your note: that m05171400822.txt file is existed. But when I tried click that link  using firefox, there is no appear anything.

Please help to advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [http](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or [ftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) for remote files:

```
http://192.168.182.23/dt/rm/pass/m05171400822.txt
ftp://192.168.182.23/dt/rm/pass/m05171400822.txt
```

Of course you need a web- or ftp serer on the remote site.

Comment: 192.168.182.23 is a file server not a web server

Comment: What means file server? samba?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with `\` at

```
<?php echo $status;?>\<?php echo $rm.".txt";?>
```

but even if its an local file if you are using ip you should use `http://` or `ftp://` instead of `file://`.
Also You have repeated `<?php echo $rm.".txt";?>` 3 times which may also cause problem.